# Deploy a Spring boot Angular app toTomcat server

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I have a Spring boot Angular app and I want to deploy it on Tomcat. For the app, I have a Maven project
with two submodules one for the front and one for the back. Iam able to generte the war file and run the app with the command mvn spring-boot:run. But unfortunately, when a drop the war file on the folder webapps and restart the Tomcat server I have an error 404 on the ressouces files lik (css, js). A I have read topics that tells to modify the base url with the folder name of the app but it doesn't work. Strangely in the generated html the base url is ok but when I look in chrome debbuger the base url is always  (even when I restart the server and disable cache)

here is my setting:

BACKEND POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bonapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>The backend module built with Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.16.18</org.projectlombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bon-app</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>core</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integ</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>integ</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

FRONTEND POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bonapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>frontend</name>
    <description>The frontend module built with Angular here,</description>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/frontend</directory>
                <targetPath>static</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/angular</workingDirectory>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.16.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

PARENT POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bonapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>core</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->

    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>backend</module>
        <module>frontend</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the pakage.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --base-href=/core/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

In angular.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../../../target/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

I don't know where is my mistake, is there some configuration to add in Tomcat? My server Tomcat is in version 9 and the generate the war I use commande: mvn clean install. The war file is generated in the backend in folder target and I past it in the folder webapps an I restart Tomcat.

Comment: can you please share the tomcat log ?

Comment: can you please explain some points in more detail.

Comment: can you please explain some points in more detail.
1. which war are you dropping to tomcat - backend (which seems to be named core.war) or frontend?
2. how does the index.html from within the war looks like? looking at package.json says, that angular should write `<base href="/core/">` into it. To which url are the links for `runtime.js`or the css pointing?

Comment: I saw, that you only build one war. ... another questions: how is the frontend packed into your war? currently it seems, that your war does not contain any of the angular stuff
maybe only because of the wrong dependency `com.bon-app:frontend` instead of `com.bonapp` but then I'm still missing some maven configuration, which puts the compiled angular app into the war.
From my experience it's not easy to server an angular app from within an spring boot war and make it running in WAR mode AND Standalone mode

Comment: @RobertKleinschmager Tkank you, this was my mistake. Now Iam able to deploy the war core.war (contains the front and back) on tomcat after generate it with mvn clean install.